# I have a problem with pulling data from mysql server in the same network using mysql1(Flutter)

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, mysql-connector

I'm developing a mobile application and this mobile application needs to pull data from mysql. For testing purposes, my simulator device and my computer need to be connected to the same network and the simulator device needs to pull data from mysql server running on my computer, please help (Tools I use: Flutter , mysql1)

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the problem? Is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with this. Even if on the same network, the database should run on it's own port.

From the mysql1 documentation:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 3306,
  user: 'bob',
  password: 'wibble',
  db: 'mydb'
);
var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
```

However, on the long run, you might want to write a backend for the app and use REST or GraphQL from the app to interact with it. If you'll directly do the queries from the app, each time you change anything in schema, your users will need to update the app (and they won't). This way, if you expose it through an endpoint, they won't care what happens behind the scenes.